# How can I efficiently clone a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++

I have a class which is a templated smart pointer meant for wrapping dynamically allocated arrays. I know that there are classes in the STL that can be used for this, especially in C++11, but this is a widely-used internal class.

I wish to write a Clone() method for it. My initial implementation used std::copy, but I realized I should be able to avoid the default construction when allocating the array.

[My attempt](http://codepad.org/qCl0EI3E) at a PoC ends up with a segmentation fault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class A
{
public:
    A(int j) : i(j) {}
    ~A() {std::cout << "Destroying " << i << std::endl;}

private:
int i;
};

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

    A* arr = static_cast<A*>(::operator new[](sizeof(A) * 3));
    std::uninitialized_copy(a, a + 3, arr);
    delete [] arr;//::operator delete[](arr);
}
```

How do I create a dynamically allocated array of T, initialized with std::uninitialized_copy, so that it can be deleted with 'delete []' (i.e. treated as if it was allocated with a simple 'new T[N]')?

---

Since it seems people have had trouble understanding what I'm asking, here's the essence of my question:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
T* CloneArray(T* in_array, size_t in_count)
{
    if (!in_array)
        return nullptr;

    T* copy = new T[in_count];
    try
    {
        std::copy(in_array, in_array + in_count, copy);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete [] copy;

        throw;
    }

    return copy;
}
```

How would I rewrite this function in a way that prevents `T::T()` from being called (if it even exists!), while returning the exact same result (let's assume our types are well behaved in that `T t; t = other;` and `T t(other);` are equivalent), including the fact that the result of the function can be deleted using the standard `delete []` operator.

Comment: `so that it can be deleted with 'delete []'` -- Why is that a requirement? Why not just delete it correctly?

Comment: Yeah that's weird, delete [] is for arrays. Besides, the point of abstractions allowed by C++ is to NOT explicitly use new and delete.

Comment: Nothing hinders you to use a std::vector internally.

Comment: This is just a class that wraps a dynamically allocated array. The array can come from anywhere, so the assumption is that it was allocated with new[]. Now, I want to treat the cloned arrays homogeneously with the 'non-cloned' ones, so I don't want to store a flag in the class telling me how it was allocated.

Also, users of the class can 'detach' the wrapped array if they wish, so they need to know how to deallocate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `new` and `delete` expressions are very simplistic tools, and should probably be avoided by everybody at all times.

Comment: @Bwmat `A* arr = static_cast<A*>(::operator new[](sizeof(A) * 3));` think over this expression thoroughly! Especially regarding what `sizeof(A)` actually does!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Allocates enough memory to hold 3 A's? sizeof(A) == number of bytes needed to store 1 A...

Comment: what is wrong with `std::shared_ptr`? or `boost::shared_ptr` if you don't have c++11?

Comment: @Mgetz - This class is for unique ownership of dynamically allocated arrays. In many cases it's used for interoperating with c-style APIs (such as when they return a 'buffer', and we do not wish to copy it simply to store it in an std::vector), and the Clone() which I wish to implement needs to do a deep copy of the array, not simply increment a reference count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I create a dynamically allocated array of T, initialized with std::uninitialized_copy, so that it can be deleted with 'delete []' (i.e. treated as if it was allocated with a simple 'new T[N]')?

So, given the relatively simple requirement that the memory be able to be deleted with `delete[]`, lets see what options we have.

*Note: All quotes from the standard are from the C++14 draft N3797 and I'm not the best at standard-interpreting so take this with a grain of salt.*

### Mixing `malloc()/free()` and `new[]/delete[]`

Undefined, since new doesn't necessarily call malloc, see **§18.6.1/4** (default behavior of `operator new`):

> Default behavior:
>
> - Executes a loop: Within the loop, the function first attempts to allocate the requested storage. Whether the attempt involves a call to the Standard C library function malloc is unspecified.

### Avoiding default-initialization

So, seeing that we're required to use `new[]` if we want to use `delete[]`,
looking at the standard for information about initialization in a *new-expression* **§5.3.4/17**:

> A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:
>
> - If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
> - Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

and going to **§8.5/7**:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;

we see that if we omit a *new-initializer* in our `new[]`, all the elements of the array will be default initialized via their default constructors.

So, what if we include a *new-initializer*, do we have any options? Going back to its definition in **§5.3.2/1**:

> new-initializer:
>
> - (expression-list opt)
> - braced-init-list

The only possibility we are left with is a *braced-init-list* (*expression-list* is for non-array *new-expressions*). I managed to get it working for objects with compile time size, but obviously that's not terribly helpful. For reference (portions of code adapted from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    int id;
    A(int i) : id(i) {
        std::cout << "c[" << id << "]\t";}
    A() : A(0) {}

    ~A() {std::cout << "d[" << id << "]\t";}
};

template<class T, std::size_t ...I>
T* template_copy_impl(T* a, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return new T[sizeof...(I)]{std::move(a[I])...};
}

template<class T, std::size_t N,
    typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
T* template_copy(T* a) {
    return template_copy_impl<T>(a, Indices());
}

int main()
{
    const std::size_t N = 3;

    A* orig = new A[N];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // modify original so we can see whats going on
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        orig[i].id = 1 + i;

    A* copy = template_copy<A, N>(orig);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        copy[i].id *= 10;

    delete[] orig;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete[] copy;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which when compiled with `-std=c++1y` (or equivalent) should output something like:

```
c[0]    c[0]    c[0]
d[3]    d[2]    d[1]
d[30]   d[20]   d[10]
```

### Different types in `new[]` vs `delete[]`

To summarize, not only are we required to use `new[]` if we want to use `delete[]` but when omitting a *new-initializer*, our objects are default-initialized. So, what if we allocate memory using a fundamental type (similar, in a way, to using placement new), it will leave the memory uninitialized, right? Yes, but its undefined to delete the memory with something like `T* ptr = /* whatever */; delete[] ptr` if it was allocated with a different type. See **§5.3.5/2**:

> In the second alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array new-expression. If not, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: this means that the syntax of the delete-expression must match the type of the object allocated by new, not the syntax of the new-expression. — end note ]

and **§5.3.5/3**, which hints at the same thing:

> In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

### Other options?

Well, you could still use `unique_ptr`s as others have suggested. Although given that you're stuck with a large code base it's probably not feasible. Again for reference, here's what my humble implementation might look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    int id;
    A(int i) : id(i) {
        std::cout << "c[" << id << "]\t";}
    A() : A(0) {}

    ~A() {std::cout << "d[" << id << "]\t";}
};

template<class T>
struct deleter
{
    const bool wrapped;
    std::size_t size;

    deleter() :
        wrapped(true), size(0) {}
    explicit deleter(std::size_t uninit_mem_size) :
        wrapped(false), size(uninit_mem_size) {}

    void operator()(T* ptr)
    {
        if (wrapped)
            delete[] ptr;
        else if (ptr)
        {
            // backwards to emulate destruction order in
            // normally allocated arrays
            for (std::size_t i = size; i > 0; --i)
                ptr[i - 1].~T();
            std::return_temporary_buffer<T>(ptr);
        }
    }
};

// to make it easier on ourselves
template<class T>
using unique_wrap = std::unique_ptr<T[], deleter<T>>;

template<class T>
unique_wrap<T> wrap_buffer(T* orig)
{
    return unique_wrap<T>(orig);
}

template<class T>
unique_wrap<T> copy_buffer(T* orig, std::size_t orig_size)
{
    // get uninitialized memory
    auto mem_pair = std::get_temporary_buffer<T>(orig_size);

    // get_temporary_buffer can return less than what we ask for
    if (mem_pair.second < orig_size)
    {
        std::return_temporary_buffer(mem_pair.first);
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    // create a unique ptr with ownership of our memory, making sure to pass
    // the size of the uninitialized memory to the deleter
    unique_wrap<T> a_copy(mem_pair.first, deleter<T>(orig_size));

    // perform the actual copy and return the unique_ptr
    std::uninitialized_copy_n(orig, orig_size, a_copy.get());
    return a_copy;
}


int main()
{
    const std::size_t N = 3;

    A* orig = new A[N];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // modify original so we can see whats going on
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        orig[i].id = 1 + i;

    unique_wrap<A> orig_wrap = wrap_buffer(orig);

    {
        unique_wrap<A> copy = copy_buffer(orig, N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            copy[i].id *= 10;

        // if we are passing the original back we can just release it
        A* back_to_somewhere = orig_wrap.release();

        delete[] back_to_somewhere;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which should output:

```
c[0]    c[0]    c[0]
d[3]    d[2]    d[1]
d[30]   d[20]   d[10]
```

Lastly, you might be able to override the global or class `operator new/delete`, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: Very good answer, very thorough. You've convinced me to give up on this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Since A already is a smart pointer to a class that wraps dynamically allocated memory, it's guaranteed that the memory will not be deallocated until all references are released. Thus you can use a simple array or vector and copy the smart pointers around, no need to dynamically allocate the array.

For example:

```
typedef sdt::vector<A<SomeType> > AVector;

AVector copy(AVector in)
{
   AVector copyArray = in;
   return copyArray;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be able to wrap memory which was already allocated using new[] by someone else.

Comment: "it's guaranteed that the memory will not be deallocated until all references are released" is wrong. It wouldn't even be the case if `A<>` were `std::shared_pointer<>`. It takes much more than the implementation of `A<>` given by the OP to create a smart pointer!

Comment: Obviously what OP has given is greatly simplified example. A is an internal class his organization is using widely, thus the assumption is that it works fine.

Comment: No, I don't think it is. I think `A` is exactly what is presented here. He is just using it as a class with a noisy destructor in order to know whether he is deallocating his objects properly. The actual smart pointer class is not present, he is only asking about the implementation of a portion of it.

Comment: yes, ventsyv is right. This is just for a new feature (cloning) that I'm trying to add.

I was reviewing some code, and found a few places that were doing the cloning manually with memcpy, so I wanted to just create a convenience method for it. Our class is something that could easily be replaced with something like std::unique_ptr (with a custom deleter) except for a few conveniences like an operator[] overload, and the fact that it would break a ton of code that relies on it.